# How to persist a Firebase login?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm doing an app with Ionic Framework and Firebase. I made a custom login to get data inside Firebase, but every single time  the app is restarted I need to login again. How can I persist the login? The user should login the first time, and not need to do it again.

Here is my service:

```js
(function() {
 'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mytodo.login')
        .factory('LoginService', LoginService);

    LoginService.$inject = ['$state', '$ionicLoading', '$firebaseAuth', '$firebaseObject','$rootScope', '$timeout', 'fb', '$q'];

    function LoginService($state, $ionicLoading, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject, $rootScope, $timeout, fb, $q){
        

        var service = {
            CustomLogin: CustomLogin,
            GetCurrentUser: GetCurrentUser,
            RegisterUser: RegisterUser,
        };
        return service;

        function CustomLogin(email, password) {
            if(email ==null | password == null){
                console.log('Preencha todos os campos!');
                return;
            }

            $ionicLoading.show({
                showBackdrop: false,
                 template: '<p>Carregando...</p><ion-spinner icon="android" style="stroke: #1d9c9e;fill:#1d9c9e;"></ion-spinner>'
            });

            $firebaseAuth().$signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(authData) {
                $rootScope.currentUser = GetCurrentUser(authData.uid);

                $timeout(function() {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $state.go('tab.todo', {});
                }, 1000);

            }).catch(function(error) {
                showToast();
               
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                
                console.log(error);
            });
        }

         function showToast(){ 
            ionicToast.show('Usuário ou senha inválido', 'middle', false, 1500);
        }


        function GetCurrentUser(userId) {
            var query = fb.child('/users/' + userId);
            var currentUser = $firebaseObject(query)
            return currentUser;
        }

        function SaveUser(authData) {

            console.log(authData.uid);
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            
            var uid = authData.uid;
            var user = {
                displayName: authData.displayName,
                name: authData.displayName,
                photoURL: authData.photoURL,
                email: authData.email,
                emailVerified: authData.emailVerified,
                providerId: authData.providerData[0].providerId
            };

            var ref = fb.child('/users/' + uid);
            ref.once("value")
                .then(function(snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        console.log('User already exists');
                    } else {
                        ref.set(user);
                    }

                    deffered.resolve(snapshot);
                });

            return deffered.promise;
        };

        function RegisterUser(user) {
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            $ionicLoading.show();
            $firebaseAuth().$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).then(function(authData) {
                var newUser = {
                    name: user.name,
                    email: user.email,
                    providerId: authData.providerData[0].providerId
                };

                var userId = authData.uid;
                var ref = fb.child('/users/' + userId);
                ref.once("value")
                    .then(function(snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            //console.log('User already exists');
                        } else {
                            ref.set(newUser).then(function(user){
                                $rootScope.currentUser = GetCurrentUser(userId);
                            })
                        }

                        deffered.resolve(snapshot);
                        CustomLogin(user.email, user.password);
                    });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                var errorCode = error.code;
                console.log(errorCode);

                if(errorCode === 'auth/weak-password')
                    ionicToast.show('Erro, a senha precisa ter no mínimo 6 digitos.', 'middle', false, 3000);
                
                if(errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use')
                    ionicToast.show('Erro, o email: ' + user.email + ' já existe em nossa base de dados.', 'middle', false, 3000);
            })

            return deffered.promise;
        };
    }
})();
```

Answer (score -31, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this. Maybe it's not the most correct anwser for it, but it worked for me. I used localSotrage to store the username and password. I could store the tolken as well, but I want to create a "remember password" screen.
 When I do my first login I do this in my service.

service.js when I store the user data;

```js
localStorage.setItem("uPassword",password);
localStorage.setItem("uEmail",email);
```

And I add the following if statement in my controller. If i already did the login, I use the e-mail and password to login again. If I dont, I wait to user press the button and call de function in my service.

controller.js if statement:

```js
if(localStorage.getItem("uEmail")!==undefined && localStorage.getItem("uPassword")!==undefined) {
  LoginService.CustomLogin(localStorage.getItem("uEmail"),localStorage.getItem("uPassword"))
 }
```

Comment: Its a bad practice and makes developers look bad if you store user credentials un hashed in local storage. I wouldn't use your app.

Comment: @mbejda I totally agree with you, this was three years ago when I was starting to code. I'm ashemed about what I did in my very beginning, I woudn't advise any one to do this or to use this app ( PS.: this app is not, never was, and never will be in production )

Comment: @LucasGaspar What you can do is change the accepted answer to be @ Christo Goosen's

Answer (score 11):

### Newer version

Initialize the app like this to keep the user logged in even after the browser is closed and reopened on the same device.

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, browserLocalPersistence, setPersistence } from 'firebase/auth'

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
(async () => {
  await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
})();
```

To get the user object you can use [React Firebase Hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-hooks):

```js
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this just saved me after days of search

Comment: small detail:

if you are checking if user exist or not inside of let's say master layout, you have to wait until it's loading. 

full example here:
https://github.com/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/09bf06b28c82b4c3c1beabb1b32a8007232ed045/auth

Answer (score 10):

To re-iterate the point of don't persist the login yourself, firebase does this for you. I am referencing this from typescript FYI.

In the official docs() :

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
```

Where local is on disk.

Then later in your code all you need to do is subscribe to the onAuthStateChanged observable.

```
this.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user){
```

Do not persist the plain text password yourself!!!! Firebase persists a user with uid, session API keys etc.

Just follow the Firebase docs. Persisting plain text password will result in a bad security audit.

Comment: I used firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
however nothing is persisted on refresh

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't persist username and password to storage, if you have to then at least store the password as a hash.

Firebase has the following for signing in again:
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

});